# python dictionary operation to add all possible fields

Tags: python

I have a `list` named `attributes` which contains all possible fields. Like this:

```
attributes = [
    'name',
    'phone_no',
    'address',
    'hobby',
]
```

I also have some `dictionaries` which have some `key-value` pairs, and the `keys` are always a subset of the `attributes` list. One such `dictionary` is:

```
my_dict = {'name': "Kanchon Gharami", 'address': "Bangladesh"}
```

Here in this dictionary only two `keys` (`name` & `address`) are present, rest of the two fields(`phone_no` & `hobby`) from the `attribute` list are not present.

I need to convert it in such a way that it holds all the possible fields as a `key` and value `NAN` if no value is given; something like this:

```
my_dict = {'name': "Kanchon Gharami", 'phone_no' : "NAN", 'address': "Bangladesh", 'hobby' : "NAN"}
```

Please advise me how to do this with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use dictionary comprehension:

```
attributes = [
'name',
'phone_no',
'address',
'hobby',
]
#the dictionary has to be filled with some attrs
dictionary = {attr:"NAN" if attr not in dictionary.keys() else dictionary[attr] for attr in attributes}
```

you could do like this:

```
attributes = [
'name',
'phone_no',
'address',
'hobby',
]
dictionary = dict()
for attr in attribute:
    if attr not in dictionary:
        dictionary[attr] = "NAN"
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use `defaultdict`.

Otherwise, you can just loop over your `attributes` list and add them as keys to your dict.

Answer (score 1):

have a base dict and then update the fields that you have in your `my_dict`

```
attributes = [
    'name',
    'phone_no',
    'address',
    'hobby',
]

my_dict = {'name': "Kanchon Gharami", 'address': "Bangladesh"}
attributes_tpl = [('name', "NaN"), ('phone_no', "NaN"), ('address', "NaN"), ('hobby', "NaN")]
base_dict = dict(attributes_tpl)
base_dict.update(my_dict)
print(base_dict)
```

Comment: Rather than typing out `attributes_tpl`, you could create it as a list comprehension from `attributes`. Or better yet use a dict comprehension to create `base_dict` directly.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes, I did that purposely as I wanted to show one of the case of using ```update``` function of dict. not everyone is familiar with yet. people use ```dict[key] = value``` almost everywhere.

Comment: You can create `base_dict` more directly with a dict comprehension and still use `update()`. These two issues are independent.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example I’m going to cook up for you, tell me if I’ve misinterpreted the question.

```py
myAttributes = [“name”, “phone”, “address”, “hobby”]
myDict = {“name”: “Kanchon”, “address”: “myHouse”}
newDict = dict()
for item in myAttributes:
   for key, value in myDict.items():
       if key == item:
          newDict[key] = value
          continue
       newDict[key] = None
```

I’m afraid I can’t test this but I would love to hear if it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
attributes = [
    'name',
    'phone_no',
    'address',
    'hobby',
]
my_dict = {'name': "Kanchon Gharami", 'phone_no' : "NAN", 'address': "Bangladesh", 'hobby' : "NAN"}

mydict=dict()

for l in attributes:
    if l=='phone_no':
        mydict[l]="NAN"
    else:
        mydict[l]="test"
print(mydict)
```